# How do you reset a View Controller?

Tags: swift

I want to reset a View Controller so that when I do, the app is like it has been reset. Basically, I want to make it so that it is the same as if the user has closed and relaunched app, except with a function.

EDIT: Sorry for not being so clear. I want to be able to reset the view controller WHILE I am inside of it. All  I have is a couple of animations that move things around and change text of UILabels, nothing more. For now, I have 2 workarounds in the comments below, but they seem really inefficient.

Comment: Well, this depends how your VC is setup. You'll need to give us some code to work with at the very least.

Comment: To give you an answer that's as specific as your question: "By changing some code." Persistence is something you have to implement yourself. If your view controller saves it's state, it only does that because you taught it to do that. We don't know what you did, so we can't tell you how to reset it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought there would be a function of view controller that you could call to reset its state. My View Controller has a bunch of animations that move around objects and images on the screen, and there are labels that change their text. I just wanted all of these to reset to their original state (the labels change back to original text, the images appear back in their original positions.) I thought there would be a simple method in Xcode that would automatically do this. For now, I've created a function that sets all the positions/text back to their original manually.

Comment: I've thought of some workarounds that could also work, such as just going to another blank view controller that instantly. As soon as the "Done" button is clicked, it takes you to another view controller that is blank, but instantly returns you back to the original so that it resets. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As Duncan C has mentioned there is no **cheap** way to reset a VC if you look for a one liner solution. And the more complex VC is the more work
you'd have to do to implement your reset functionality (which will then
be likely subject to code rot depending on how frequently you are going
to test it OR suck your time and money if you try to maintain it).
I assume your VC is complex cause if it was a two labels and a button kind
of thing I'm sure you would've figured out the required 3-liner
reset function by now.